# Internet Explorer 8 - Developer Tools and Framesets

Tags: ie-developer-tools

MS ***can't*** have crippled IE Toolbar. I must be doing something wrong.

How do I use IE8 Developer tools to browse the DOM/CSS/JS of a frameset site?

---

I developed a site that uses framesets to achieve a AJAX like effect(it pre-dated AJAX!) -

Now it has developed a small css fault in IE8, but I can't investigate via IE8 Developer Tools.......

I used IE developer toolbar to build the site in the first place - now I feel let down.

Answer (score 0):

Press F12 to bring up MS' version of FireBug which is built into IE8. (Menu: Tools | Developer Tools.)

Comment: I know that! Its the Frameset browsing that missing

Comment: Wasn't clear... developer toolbar is an add on for previous versions and a different thing to IE8's inbuilt developer tools.
From an earlier question here... IE8's dev tools seem to sometimes have a problem with (i)frames.